Plotly: updating the "z-axis" hover format on a 2d scatter chart
I have a 2d scatter plot and the colour of the markers represents the 'z' column of a dataframe. I have the hover tool set up to display the x-axis data, y-axis data and the 'z' data mentioned above. I can format the hover tool x and y data by using:
    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis=dict(hoverformat='.3r'),
        yaxis=dict(hoverformat='.3r')

Is it possible to update the "z-axis" or "z data" in a similar manner?
Many thanks.

Not the most elegant, but you can create a new z_formatted column in your DataFrame with the desired formatting, then pass this column to px.scatter using the custom_data parameter and explicitly define the hovertemplate to include this new column instead of the original z data.
For example:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'y': [10,11,12,13,14],
    'z': [2,2,3,3,4]
})

df['z_formatted'] = df['z'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:.3f}')

fig = px.scatter(df, x='x', y='y', color='z', custom_data=['z_formatted'])

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(hoverformat='.3r'),
    yaxis=dict(hoverformat='.3r')
)

fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join([
        "x: %{x}",
        "y: %{y}",
        "z: %{customdata}",
    ])
)

fig.show()


